# can't edit link on gazebo 5.1

Tags: gazebo-model

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi

I just installed gazebo 5.1.0 and I was following the [model editor tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=model_editor&cat=model_editor_top). After I added some simple shapes and I tried to right-click the simple shapes to edit the link. There was no menu shows up for link inspector. what's wrong here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8661/can%27t-edit-link-on-gazebo-5.1/) by [mugenHexapod](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1197/mugenhexapod/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 17 on 2015-05-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The model editor tools on the tutorial will be available from Gazebo 6, to be released on [July 2015](http://gazebosim.org/#collapseVersion6_0).

You can see which version the tutorial applies to on its top-right corner.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2015-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mugenHexapod](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1197/mugenhexapod/) on 2015-05-11**:
thank you.